# Incomplete list of synset hypernyms in NLTK's WordNet?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

While trying to recover any given WordNet synset's hypernyms through WN NLTK's interface, I am getting what I think are different results from WN's web search interface. For example:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
bank6ss = wn.synsets("bank")[5]  # 'bank' as gambling house funds
bank6ss.hypernyms()
# returns [Synset('funds.n.01')]
```

That is, only one hypernym found (no others are found with, for instance, `instance_hypernyms()`). However, when looking at [WN's web interface](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&r=2&s=bank&i=6&h=0000011130000000002000000000000#c), this sense of 'bank' lists several other hypernyms under "Direct hypernym":

```
funds, finances, monetary resource, cash in hand, pecuniary resource
```

What would explain this difference, and how could I get that longer list of hypernyms in NLTK's WordNet?

The WordNet version used in my NLTK installation is 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that I'm looking at two different types of output: What is returned in NLTK WordNet is a hypernym *synset* (`Synset['funds.n.01']`) while the list of hypernyms in the web interface is composed of *lemmas* belonging to that one synset.

To fully answer the question, this list of lemmas can be recovered in NLTK as follows:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
bank6ss = wn.synsets("bank")[5]  # 'bank' as gambling house funds
hn1ss = bank6ss.hypernyms()[0]
hn1ss.lemmas()
# returns [Lemma('funds.n.01.funds'), 
#   Lemma('funds.n.01.finances'),
#   Lemma('funds.n.01.monetary_resource'), 
#   Lemma('funds.n.01.cash_in_hand'),
#   Lemma('funds.n.01.pecuniary_resource')]
```

Or, if only lemma names are of interest:

```
hn1ss.lemma_names()
# returns [u'funds',
#   u'finances',
#   u'monetary_resource',
#   u'cash_in_hand',
#   u'pecuniary_resource']
```